# yii 1.1 error installing yiibehaviorsluggable extension

Tags: php, yii

I want to install `yiibehaviorsluggable` extension as it is written here

> http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/yiibehaviorsluggable/

But I get the error : `" Alias "ext.behaviors.SluggableBehavior.SluggableBehavior" is invalid.` Make sure it points to an existing PHP file and the file is readable. "

I copied `yii-behavior-sluggable-master` directory into `/protected/extensions` directory.

What I missed if I have in some way in write this extension in config file? Or what is the reason of this error?

Answer (score 0):

In yii the alias `ext.behaviors.SluggableBehavior.SluggableBehavior` is referring to the file `/protected/extensions/behaviors/SluggableBehavior/SluggableBehavior.php`

Basically each `.` is replace by a `/` (or `\`) and `ext` is a shortcut to the extension directory. The text after the last point is the name of the class.

So if you put your file `SluggableBehavior.php` in `/protected/extensions/yii-behavior-sluggable-master` you should use the alias `ext.yii-behavior-sluggable-master.SluggableBehavior` in your code.